# Is it possible to see on which Google result page a website is?

Tags: google-search

I was just wondering whether or not it is possible to obtain information about the rank of a website for a given search term on `Google`, or on which page it is.

> E.g. if you search for 'computer' then (currently) the website **www.ehow.com/computers/** is on page 2.

Especially when you don't know on which page your website is, it is a painful task to check each page for a search term. So is there a general way to know on which page a website is for a given search term on Google?

Comment: Please note that Google search results are different for everyone and if you see something as first (or Nth) result, that does not means that your target population will see it that way. Also, I'm voting to close and migrate to appropriate site, since questions about web applications are not welcome here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to play with Google's [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) which gives you an interface to see how Google ranks your site, and check out various statistics and optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can get various tools for it. Google's own webmaster tools allows you to see rankings of various keywords in your webpage. Webmasters shows in which position it is listed. Guessing 10 reults per page you can easily calculate which page.

Third party tools are abundant and they will give you so many details regarding page position, competitor etc. One such software is [traffictravis](http://www.traffictravis.com), I used this software to get statistics on that keyword.